# Ruby/Rake: Why isn't the CSV file open for reading?

Tags: ruby, file, csv, rake

I want to drop the top two rows from a CSV file and add my own header. I have wrapped this in a rake task.

```rb
task :fix_csv do
  # copy to temp file
  cp ENV['source'], TMP_FILE

  # drop header rows
  table = CSV.table(TMP_FILE)
  File.open(TMP_FILE, 'w') do |f|
    f.write(table.drop(2).to_csv)
  end

  # add new header
  CSV.open(TMP_FILE, 'w', force_quotes: true) do |csv|
    csv << HEADERS if csv.count.eql? 0
  end

  puts 'Done!'
end
```

However, this fails with an error:

```
rake aborted!
IOError: not opened for reading
../rakefile.rb:54:in `count'
```

Line 54 is:

`csv << HEADERS if csv.count.eql? 0`

Why can't it read the file? Do I need to explicitly close the file after I've removed the first two rows?

Answer (score 0):

The second time you open the file for writing only, but then you are trying to iterate getting an access to content (namely by querying the row count):

```
#                  ⇓⇓⇓
CSV.open(TMP_FILE, 'w', force_quotes: true) do |csv|
#                       ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  csv << HEADERS if csv.count.eql? 0
end
```

while it’s easy to fix, may I ask what would be wrong with forgetting about `CSV` in total, in favor of somewhat like:

```
old = File.readlines(FILE_NAME).drop(2)
old[0...0] = HEADERS.join(',')
File.write(FILE_NAME, old)
```

?